# My Sql Signup code not working

Tags: php, sql

This is my signup script, its not giving me any erros but it wont place data into the table not sure what to do: I think that it might be some simple syntax error but I am unable to find it. This sentence is here because it is asking me to add more info but I have none so here is the code:

```
<?php 
include "dbConfig.php";
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post') {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `members`(`name`, `password`) VALUES ($name, $password)";
}
?>


<form name="frmregister" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" size="30" />
    <input type="password" name="password" size="30" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" alt="Submit" title="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" alt="Reset" title="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: I believe the REQUEST_METHOD index will be in uppercase, so as a shot in the dark, can you try capitalizing POST in the if statement and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: you are using wrong quote. you using ( ` = backtick ), please use ( ' = single quote).

Comment: I did all you said still nothing

Comment: What happends when you sent the post data? is it a blank screen or just the same again?

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: @TrevorClarke, please continue using backtick. That is correct. Also, Rou has an answer that works if you don't mind sql injection attacks. edit- Rou ALMOST has an answer that works.

Comment: You have an sql statement but where are you doing the query part `mysqli_query()` or similar?

Comment: haha @Rasclatt ofc that's the problem :D

Comment: NEVER use md5 for password hashing! everything is broken here. please don't go on with this code, get professional help and let a developer do this, you'll only run into huge problems otherwise.

Comment: @Sliq maybe he's learning?

Comment: @EricLandvall this is my first script. So Calm yourselfs, also this if for a fun project so professional help is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't quite doing anything really. Here is how you should insert data into a table with mysqli object-oriented:

```
$servername = "Server Name";
$username = "Username";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "Database Name";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post') {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
    $pass = md5($_POST["password"]);  

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (name,password)
    VALUES ('".$name."','".$pass."')";

    $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
}
```

More on inserting data on table with Mysqli Object Oriented [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp).

Thanks [**Erik**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/570796/erik-landvall) and [**Shahar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658226/shahar) for the security tips!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Don't you need a query? You have just opened a connection and closed it again.

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, I'm an idiot and erased something I shouldn't have, it's fixed now.

Comment: If you're going to fix his code at least tell him about the security holes.

Comment: I don't get paid enough. Wait, I don't get paid at all. Do you mean using `htmlentities()`?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the name

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `members`(`name`, `password`) VALUES ($name, $password)";
```

To:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `members`(`name`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$password')";
```

Then run the query:

```
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

...like so, or similar (`$connection` should be set in you config file, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: DONT promote the usage of `mysql_query`, it's outdated for 5+ years now.

Comment: I know, just don't know how he setts up the database connection, wonted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Landvall ok so i get this error when i do what you say: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/howto570/public_html/signup.php on line 10

Comment: @TrevorClarke You are using `mysql_query` you should use `mysqli_query`. the `i` stands for `improved`

Comment: @Landvall I get this error:  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/howto570/public_html/signup.php on line 10

Comment: @Landvall (sorry about that other comment that was for ecric not you.

Comment: Update your question with the code you have now, then I can help you

Comment: 1. deprecated. 2. SQL injection.

Comment: @Shahar It's his first script, I'm sure he will learn all about injections later on. But Treveor, if you actually are going to use this on a live server, you need to look over the security in your script a lot. `mysqli_query` is not deprecated?

Comment: @ErikLandvall I talked about his original code. 3. MD5 hash.