# Login returns password does not match in php

Tags: php, html

I hope you are doing great. I have within my project a login functionality. when I try to login. It gives me this strange error that I did not write within my login.php script. I wrote it somewhere else and did not make an import to it. I hope you guys can help me identify the problem.


Thanks in Advance. Cheers,

Some useful pieces of my code:

Login.php Script:

```
    <?php
include_once 'Header.php';
?>
<style>
    #container {
        height: 92vh;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <br>


    <?php
    $_SESSION['logged'] = null;

//in this page we do things slightly differently - the code for validation and displaying messages is done
//before we display the form 
    echo '<div id = "div_1"><h1>Login</h1>';

//display the form
    echo '<div id="div_2"><div id="div_2">
       <form action="Login.php" method="post">
           <label>Email<br>
           <span class="small">enter your Email</span>
           </label>
           <input type="text" name="Email" value=""/>
           <label><br>Password<br>
           <span class="small">enter your password</span>
           </label>
           <input type="password" name="Password" />

           <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />Log in</button>
           <input type ="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
         </form>
         </div>
    </div>';

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        //require_once is similar to 'include' but ensures the code is not copied multiple times
        require_once('LoginFunctions.php');
        $name3 = $_POST['Email'];
        $pwd3 = $_POST['Password'];
        echo $name3;
        echo $pwd3;
        //list() is a way of assigning multiple values at the same time
        //checkLogin() function returns an array so list here assigns the values in the array to $check and $data
        list($check, $data) = checkLogin($_POST['Email'], $_POST['Password']);


        if ($check) {
            setcookie('FName', $data['FName'], time() + 900);  //cookie expires after 15 mins
            setcookie('LName', $data['LName'], time() + 900);
            //
            //use session variables instead of cookies
            //these variables should now be available to all pages in the application as long as the users session exists
            $_SESSION['FName'] = $data['FName'];
            $_SESSION['LName'] = $data['LName'];
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $data['Email'];
            //to enable $_SESSION array to be populated we always need to call start_session() - this is done in header.php
            //print_r is will print out the contents of an array
            print_r($_SESSION);
            //
            //Redirect to another page
            $url = absolute_url('Index.php');  //function defined in Loginfunctions.php to give absolute path for required page
            $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
            echo $_SESSION['logged'];
            //this version of the header function is used to redirect to another page
            echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = '" . $url . "';\",10000);</script>"; //since we have entered correct login details we are now being directed to the home page

            exit();
        } else {
            $errors = $data;
        }
    }

    //create a sopace between the button and the error messages
    //echo'<div class="spacer"></div>';

    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo '<br/> <p class="error">The following errors occurred: <br />';

        //foreach is a simplified version of the 'for' loop
        foreach ($errors as $err) {
            echo "$err <br />";
        }

        echo '</p>';
    }

    //this is the end of the <div> that contains the form
    echo '</div>';

    /* */
    ?>
</div>

<?php
include 'Footer.php';
?>
```

My loginFunctions.php class:

```
    <?php


function absolute_url($page = 'Index.php')
{
    //header('Location: http:\\localhost');
    //exit(); //terminates the script

    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $url = rtrim($url, '/\\');
    $url .= '/' . $page;

    return $url;
}

function checkLogin($Email = '', $password = '')
{
  $errors = array();

  if(empty($Email))
    $errors[] = 'You must enter a Email';

  if(empty($password))
    $errors[] = 'You must enter a password';

  if(empty($errors))
  {
////set up database econnection
     include 'DBConn.php';

      $db = new DBConn();
      $dbc = $db->getDBConnection();

      $q = "select Email, FName, LName from Users_1 where Email = '$Email' and Password = '$password'";

      $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

      if($r)
      {
          if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) != 0)
          {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return array(true, $row);
          }
          else
          {
            $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match';
          }
      }
      else{
        echo '<p class="error"> Oh dear. There was a database error</p>';
        echo '<p class = "error">' . mysqli_error($dbc) .'</p>';
      }

  }

  return array(false, $errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not save passwords unhashed/unencrypted. Use the Password Hashing API of PHP to hash the passwords and save their hash in the database. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: What `strange error` are you getting? Future issues, SQL injection, password hashing..

Comment: `mysqli_affected_rows` is used for returning rows affected by insert, update and delete operation. For select statement you must use `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: @chris The following errors occurred:
Passwords do not match

Comment: Try debugging the script. Use var_dump() and check, what do you get as your output for $row

Comment: @M.S.P I did, It compiled fine without errors and I used echo statements. It showed the values I entered

Comment: did you check the sql query manually?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_affected_rows` is used for returning rows affected by insert, update and delete operation. For select statement you must use `mysqli_num_rows`

```
if($r) {
       if(mysqli_num_rows($r) != 0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                return array(true, $row);
        }else {
                $errors[] = 'Passwords do not match';
        }
     }
```

For better security: you can use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function to make your password stronger and later match the hash you saved in the field (Password- datatype would be varchar with a length of 255). You match this hash using password_verify() function which has two parameters: the string that user typed and the hash saved in the database.

For example:

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

will print:

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

When a user login using rasmuslerdorf as password, you query the database and match the stored hash password `$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a` with `rasmuslerdorf` using [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) :

```
$q= mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Password FROM `Users_1` 
                      WHERE `Email` = '$Email' and `Password` = '$password'"); 
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
$hash = $res['Password'];
if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: $dbc is the mysql connection, it should be $r

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly non-technical answer but it contains my advice based on my own experience.

When I was just learning html and had no real idea about php or javascript, I would spend hours trying to figure out how logins worked.

After a while I found out about php and javascript, and I had a friends php login script to go on.

I managed to get a database working, however the signup did not which is why I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28016396/3998484) question.

Eventually I got the login working, however my limited knowledge meant that I could have been storing peoples (and friends) private information such as passwords that they use elsewhere, on a website that could have had a major flaw.

Now don't get me wrong, I am not saying don't do this I am simply saying DO YOUR RESEARCH. Take time watching videos like this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q
>
> How NOT to Store Passwords! - Computerphile

and then spend some more time doing database queries that don't involve passwords.

Once you have a good understanding of how to use queries and feel confident doing them, begin researching [hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) methods in php.

Please take a look into:

- **[Salting your passwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))** where you essentially add random
  characters to the password that is being hashed so that you cant use
  a hashing table to reverse a hashed password.
- **[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** where people use the input (name field or any other field) on your form to change the syntax of your question, and essentially add code to your website. This is dangerous because then they can (depending on what permissions the user has) drop tables, drop databases, select *, and many other harmful things. This topic is also mentioned in the video mentioned before about "How NOT to Store Passwords!".
- **[Do more research](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33585/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-secure-log-in-and-registration-for-my-website)** (don't only use that link it does not contain everything)...when you are storing peoples information you can never be too safe. Don't think of these tips as overkill, think of them as a responsibility to your users, that they can TRUST that nothing will happen to their password!

Good luck!